# Make a new array that contains only selected rows from a previous array based on a variable in a column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to make a new array that contains only selected values from a previous array based on a variable.

For instance, I have this as an array:

[image]

Using a selection box from a user form, I want to be able to pick item # 15 for instance (in column 1) and get a new array of just the rows that contain item # 15 (new array would be 3 rows by 9 columns).

any ideas how to do that? also allowing it to be dynamic since I want to be able to do this for different sets of Data. I'm not sure if it would be better to sort on two columns column 1 which is item # and the last column that corresponds to what sheet it is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. It should be installed in a standard code module. Adjust the enumerations at the top to show where the data are (presumed to be at A2:I13). The code asks you to specify an Item to extract and will print the extracted data to an area 5 rows below the original.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nws                        ' worksheet navigation
                                ' modify as required
    NwsFirstDataRow = 2
    ' columns and Array elements:-
    NwsItm = 1                  ' indicate column A
    NwsTab = 9                  ' indicate column I
End Enum


Sub Test_DataSelection()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Itm As String

    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")      ' modify as required
    With Ws
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsItm), _
                         .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsTab).End(xlUp))
    End With
    Arr = Rng.Value

    Itm = InputBox("Enter a valid Item number", "Select data", 5)
    Arr = SelectedData(Itm, Arr)

    With Ws                                         ' may specify another sheet here
        Set Rng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsItm).End(xlUp).Offset(5)
        Rng.Resize(UBound(Arr), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
    End With
End Sub

Function SelectedData(ByVal Itm As Variant, _
                      Arr As Variant) As Variant()
    ' Variatus @STO 21 Jan 2020

    Dim Fun() As Variant
    Dim Ub As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim R As Long, C As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Ub = UBound(Arr)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Itm = Val(Itm)
        ReDim Fun(1 To UBound(Arr, 2), 1 To Ub)
        For R = 1 To Ub
            If Arr(R, 1) = Itm Then
                i = i + 1
                For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
                    Fun(C, i) = Arr(R, C)
                Next C
            End If
        Next R
        ReDim Preserve Fun(1 To UBound(Fun), 1 To i)
    End If

    SelectedData = Application.Transpose(Fun)
End Function
```

Comment: The function isn’t working for me. 

Is there a way to just sort my array by the first and last column? And then make a new array from that?

Comment: My code does exactly what you first asked. Therefore, "Doesn't work for me" isn't good enough. "Sort my array by the first and last column and then make a new array from that" isn't enough either. If you wish to move the goal posts you will need to be more precise, not less. And if you think that the goal remains the same, please explain why the code that does exactly what you asked doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I was just getting an error and that’s why it wasn’t working for me. It was just that the function Itm was a value instead of a string. I fixed it and now it works fine so thank you.

Comment: is there a simple way to make itm equal to a list so that it could search for multiple items in same array? And in different columns?

Comment: I think you are heading for a rephrasing of your question. That's fine with me but it can't be done within the constraints imposed by the Comment format (sorry, I don't understand what you mean by *list* or which *array* you refer to) and, to keep this forum useful to all, it shouldn't be done for a question that has been answered. Please ask a new question, post what you have after implementing what you got from here, and point out your additional requirements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59896935/create-a-new-array-from-an-existing-array-using-selected-data-values-in-that-app

Answer (score 0):

HerLow

A basic idea that you might be able to adapt to your needs…..to answer this  …. *I want to be able to pick item # 15 for instance (in column 1) and get a new array of just the rows that contain item # 15 (new array would be 3 rows by 9 columns).*

```
Option Explicit
Sub ArrayBasedOnRowSelection()
Dim WsList As Worksheet, WsOut As Worksheet
 Set WsList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List"): Set WsOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
Dim arrIn() As Variant, arrOut() As Variant
 Let arrIn() = WsList.UsedRange
Dim Cnt As Long, strRws As String
    For Cnt = 2 To WsList.UsedRange.Rows.Count
     If arrIn(Cnt, 1) = "15" Then
      Let strRws = strRws & Cnt & " "
     Else
     End If
    Next Cnt
 Let strRws = Left$(strRws, Len(strRws) - 1)
Dim SptStr() As String: Let SptStr() = Split(strRws, " ", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
Dim RwsT() As String: ReDim RwsT(1 To UBound(SptStr()) + 1, 1 To 1)
    For Cnt = 1 To UBound(SptStr()) + 1
     Let RwsT(Cnt, 1) = SptStr(Cnt - 1)
    Next Cnt
Dim Clms() As Variant: Let Clms() = Evaluate("=Column(A:" & CL(WsList.UsedRange.Columns.Count) & ")")  '     Evaluate("=Column(A:I)")

 Let arrOut() = Application.Index(arrIn(), RwsT(), Clms())

 WsOut.Cells.Clear
 Let WsOut.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrOut(), 1), WsList.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Value = arrOut
End Sub


'   http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/1902-Function-Code-for-getting-Column-Letter-from-Column-Number?p=8824&viewfull=1#post8824
Public Function CL(ByVal lclm As Long) As String '         http://www.excelforum.com/development-testing-forum/1101544-thread-post-appendix-no-reply-needed-please-do-not-delete-thanks-4.html#post4213980
    Do: Let CL = Chr(65 + (((lclm - 1) Mod 26))) & CL: Let lclm = (lclm - (1)) \ 26: Loop While lclm > 0
End Function
```

If you run that macro , it will paste out an array 3 rows by as many columns as your used range in worksheet “List”, based on the selection 15 from column 1.

File:  ArrayfromRowsBasedOnPreviousArray.xlsm : https://app.box.com/s/h9ipfz2ngskjn1ygitu4zkqr1puuzba1

Explanation : https://www.excelforum.com/excel-new-users-basics/1099995-application-index-with-look-up-rows-and-columns-arguments-as-vba-arrays.html#post4571172

Alan